# Создание раскрывающегося списка, с поиском и возможностью выбора нескольких вариантов

Tags: javascript, html

Как создать раскрывающийся список, в котором можно будет выбирать несколько позиций без использования Ctrl и возможность произвести поиск по этим самым позициям.

Comment: Просто используйте **Select2**, [вот примеры](http://select2.github.io/select2/#basics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку select2, используете поле select и в него задаёте варианты или подгружаете их через ajax

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:
Делаешь выпадающий список с помощью разметки div с элементами. Каждому элементу соответствует checkbox.

Дальше просто, отправляешь форму с запросом в поиск с данными checkbox и выдаешь новые результаты